# Show next items from json array

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a components, which shows 3 first images from json array.
I want to add a button which will replace those first 3 items with next 3 in the same array.
I guess I'm missing something here

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import ImageList from "./ImageList";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      images: [],
        index: 0
    };
    this.toNext = this.toNext.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://picsum.photos/v2/list")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({ images: data });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error happened during fetching!', err);
        });
  }

  toNext = () => {
      this.setState({index: (this.state.index + 3)});
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h2 className="title">Images list</h2>
            <ImageList data={this.state.images}/>
            <button onClick={this.toNext} className="next-btn">Next</button>
        </div>
    )
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: perhaps missing imagelist component. I suggest you to use slice to swho a sublist

Comment: You only seem to update `index`, but never use it.

Comment: For a quick fix try changing `<ImageList data={this.state.images}/>` to `<ImageList data={this.state.images.slice(this.state.index, this.state.index+3}/>`
But you will need to handle what happens when the index becomes greater than the array length, and you can also put the *active* images in a state variable as well to avoid re-slicing on each render.

Comment: Additionally you do not need to `.bind` the `toNext` method since it is an arrow function which is already bound to this `this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index is being updated correctly, but you are not taking that updated value into account. This could be achieved by slicing the images collection in the render method:

```
render() {
    const minIndex = this.state.index;
    const maxIndex = minIndex + 3;
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h2 className="title">Images list</h2>
            <ImageList data={this.state.images.slice(minIndex, maxIndex)}/>
            <button onClick={this.toNext} className="next-btn">Next</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```